# Discrepancies between aggregated data and data seperated by the date

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have some issues with the google analytics api (GA4).
I am curreently using the GA4 Query Explorer to validate the issues (https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/).

My first Query hast the metrics activeUsers, screenPageViews and the dimensions date, pagePath. There is also a filter for a specified pagePath to keep the results small.

My problem is, that if I add date to the dimensions and sum up the activeUsers (and also screenPageViews) the count is much smaller than the aggregated data of the first view.

Can anybody help me?

I expected that the count is the same